# any one can explain me how this filter(':first').click() working?

Tags: jquery

any one can explain me how this filter(':first').click() working?

```
$(function() {
    var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
    tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();
    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function() {
        tabContainers.hide();
        tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
        $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's like this:

when you click on `div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a` . the click function defined just after the
`$('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a')` in your code will be executed. and moreover since you added another click i.e `filter(':first').click();` , the click function executed earlier,  will be executed again for
`first` ul a (i.e first link in the list)

Answer (score 1):

It creates a new jQuery object which contains the first element from `$('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a')` and then triggers the `click` event on that element.

See http://api.jquery.com/filter/ and http://api.jquery.com/click/.